# Google OAuth2 Error - Desktop App doesn't comply

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to authenticate my Desktop Application via Google OAuth 2.0. Unfortunately I'm getting the following error every time I'm calling the `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` endpoint:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure. You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules."
}
```

Following my project setup according to the Google Cloud Console:

- **Publishing Status:** Testing
- Testers added via E-Mail
- OAuth client ID for application type **Desktop app** created

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The first few steps - opening the browser and logging in with an account, that is a registered tester - works flawlessly. This is done through the following URL:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?response_type=code&client_id=<client-id>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform.read-only&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true&service=lso&o2v=2&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
```

As you can see I set `http://localhost:8080` as the `redirect_uri`. A local Webserver is running on that port and eventually - after going through the login in the browser - I get the `code` but calling the `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` endpoint with the necessary form parameters results in the 400 error mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. My Desktop application is using Ktor and this is the code that I used when sending the request to `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`:

```
val response = client.submitForm(
    url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    formParameters = Parameters.build {
        append("code", <code>)
        append("client_id", <id>)
        append("client_secret", <secret>)
        append("redirect_uri", encodedRedirectUri)
        append("grant_type", "authorization_code")
    },
)
```

The problem: My `redirect_uri`. I passed it already encoded, so my `http://localhost:8080` became `http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080` instead of `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080` (double encoded) resulting in the "400 - Bad Request" error.